# Signing string in php using certificate, verifying in C#

Tags: c#, php, certificate, signing, phpseclib

I am in need of assistance with signing a string in PHP. We are building a web application which is able to alter profile data on an external website. We want to achieve this without requiring end users to enter our password on our site. The external website therefore created an API which allows us to edit the profile as long we send them email address of the profile signed by a certificate. This allows them to check whether the request came from a trusted source (us).

We tried both native PHP functions and PHPSeclib to sign an email address using a certificate:

```
$rsa = new RSA();

$rsa->setHash("sha1");
$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

$originalkey = file_get_contents('key.ppk');

$rsa->loadKey($originalkey);

echo bin2hex($rsa->sign("test@email.nl"));

// Using native PHP methods
    $email = 'test@email.nl';

    $signature = '';

    $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents("key.ppk"));

    var_dump(openssl_sign($email, $signature, $private_key, "sha1"));

    echo bin2hex($signature);
```

The signatures are fine because PHP is able to verify the posted signatures. The webservice of the external website does not accept our signatures however. They only allow a signature length of 40 characters whilst a hexidecimal dump of our signature exceeds 1000 characters.

They sent us this C# example to sign a string but we do not have enough C# knowledge to see why the output differs.

```
   string Sign(string username, string thumbprint, string hasher = "SHA1")
    {
      var store = new

  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

      store.Open(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly |
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
      try
      {
          foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates.Find(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false))
          {
            var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            if (privateKey != null)
            {
                var bytes = privateKey.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username),
    System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create(hasher));
                return string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
            } else throw new ArgumentException("no private key");
          }
      }
      finally
      {
          store.Close();
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Is there anyone who can point us to the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To my understanding your php code is doing not what it is expected. Your php code signs email, but C# SignData *computes the hash value of the specified data and signs it.*. That is why they expect length of 40 chars, because the result of SHA1 is exactly 40 chars. So you need to first compute RSA1 hash and then sign it in your php code.

Comment: @IgorYalovoy Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if that's true. As far as I can see C# uses the SHA1 hasher parameter for the Sign method. I tried that in PHP as well using $rsa->setHash("sha1")

Comment: A signature from a 384-bit RSA key is 48 bytes (96 hex chars, 64 Base64 chars). 1024-bit RSA would be 128 bytes, and a modern size of 2048-bit RSA would be 256 bytes.  So a 40 character limit means it isn't doing RSA, or it's using RSA like a truncated HMAC.

Comment: @Gijs check documentation for [SingData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It exactly says `computes the hash value of the specified data and signs it`. Try to sign and then hash  email in your php code. You should get 40 chars outcome.

Comment: Can you post the public key and a sample signed message? I can use that to look at the formatting of the message and see how C# is formatting the data and what you'd need to do in phpseclib to get it working.